# Marketing Cloud Response Times

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Are there any metrics in Marketing Cloud that can show the amount of time Marketing Cloud responded back to an outside API request for email request?  We are see some instances of over 5 seconds in production and there are some indications that some take 3 seconds. We are trying to determine if it's a network problem or if a marketing cloud issue.

Comment: It appears that you are using a Sync call. What are your API calls doing? inserting data into a DE? Making a send? You could evaluate moving to an async process

Comment: @EazyE We're moving data into sendable data extension to send an email. Not sure what you mean when you say "evaluate moving to an async process"

Comment: You can use an async route instead of a sync route:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asynchronous_processing_scenarios.htm